# Как разбить число на части?

Tags: java, groovy

Есть число формата DDDDDRRRPC. Нужно отделить C, P, RRR, DDDDDD. Как это можно реализовать? Мне уже подсказали как это сделать в Java, но хотелось бы знать как сделать тоже самое в Groovy

Answer (score 4):

%  - операция остатка от деления, / - целочисленное деление (intdiv в groovy)

```
C = x % 10
P = (x / 10) % 10
RRR =  (x / 100) % 1000
DDDD = x / 100000
```

С поправкой на синтаксис конкретного языка работает хоть в groovy, хоть в Java без бредней с переводом в строки и назад.